# add echo described by equation to audio signal (matlab)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

A simple linear system is echo. It can be described by equation **y[n] = x[n]+ kx[n−d]**, where n represents sample, k attenuation coefficient and d lag.

How can i add echo to an input signal x in **matlab** with **convolution**?

Answer (score 2):

Your model is <s>similar to</s> FIR filtering so I think the easiest way would be to use the function `filter`. 
You need to define a filter of length `d` with the right coefficients:

```
b_echo = zeros(1,d);
b_echo(1) = 1; % original signal
b_echo(d) = k; % attenuation of the echo
y = filter(b_echo,1,x);
```

Comment: This actually *is* a FIR.